# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am new at this syntax error an need direction,
Thanks,
JR

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/content------/html/language/english/site.lang.php on line 28

Here is the lines: 28-31

define ('MSG_USERNAME_EXPLANATION', 'Example: rose789 (Don't use your email address) 
Your Username identifies you to other users.');
define ('MSG_PASSWORD_EXPLANATION', '6 characters minimum 
Enter a password that's easy for you to remember, but hard for others to guess.');

I opened the file and this error followed. I don't remember changing anything.

Answer (score 2):

This code is wrong `'Example: rose789 (Don'`  
the `'` in don't  makes the string to end. 
Use 
`define ('MSG_USERNAME_EXPLANATION', "Example: rose789 (Don't use your email address) Your Username identifies you to other users.")`  double quotes

Comment: no problem, please take a second and chose my answer as best, people get reputation that way.